# Vertical centering unknown height

Tags: css, center, vertical-alignment, centering

I'm trying to vertically center an image in a DIV that doesn't have a fixed/specified height. I've tried building on the [Centering in the unknown article on CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) but for that to work you need to specify the height. Rather deceiving article title.

Here's my JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6J2WA/

This is what I'd like (picture): http://cl.ly/image/1k0h262c2c3s

**CSS**

```
/* This parent can be any width and height */
.block {
  text-align: center;
}

/* The ghost, nudged to maintain perfect centering */
.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
   height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

/* The element to be centered, can
also be of any width and height */ 
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


.inner {
max-width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
    background: #ef4;
}

.c-3 {  
width: 29.3%;
float: left;
margin-left: 6%;
    background: #e4f;
}

#you-and-us .c-3 { width: 33.5%; }
#you-and-us .c-3:first-child { text-align: right; margin: 0; }
#you-and-us .c-3:nth-child(2) { width: 21%; text-align: center; position: relative; }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123999/center-a-div-horizontally-and-vertically

Comment: Do you really want the image in the middle to be surrounded by the pink box?

Comment: @cimmanon Its just for illustration purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you can't use the pseudo element technique is because you don't have enough ancestor elements that are 100% of the height of the `#you-and-us` element.

You can simplify the whole thing if you throw out floats and use `display: table-cell` for your `.c-3` elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/6J2WA/5/

```
/* This parent can be any width and height */
.block {
    text-align: center;
}

.inner {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ef4;
}

.c-3 {  
    display: table-cell;
    background: #e4f;
}

#you-and-us .c-3 { width: 33.5%; }
#you-and-us .c-3:first-child { text-align: right; }
#you-and-us .c-3:nth-child(2) { width: 21%; text-align: center; position: relative; background: yellow; vertical-align: middle; }
```

Comment: Thanks that does the job but when I introduce a breakpoint with media queries that basically stacks these 3 columns on top of one another with a float left. I get some odd results when I make the browser larger see: http://cl.ly/image/0g3a2e0O1x2e Any ideas how to get round this?

Comment: Really, this code should be within a media query restricting it to larger viewports (see: *mobile first*).  What do you *want* to happen for smaller viewports?

Comment: This code is a three column layout but I also have, 1, 2 and 4 column layouts. Basically with smaller viewports they just stack into one column. I am familiar with mobile first and understand your point but how can I fix the issue I have currently?

Comment: I can't really help you if all you're going to provide is a screenshot.  All that should need to be done is remove all of your floats related to these elements and hide `display: table-cell` from narrow viewports.  Narrow devices should stack vertically, wide devices will be horizontal.