# Align div to page center with dynamic size

Tags: android, html, ios, css, webview

I saw many example of how to centerize div to middle of page, but in all the examples the size of the divs was fixed.
How to put div in center of page with unknown size of div height?
(the gray div in the middle)

[My code](http://jsfiddle.net/fainick/bRgrf/):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <style>
            html,body{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
            }
            body{
                background-color: transparent; 
                overflow: hidden;
                font-family: "Helvetica"
                    ;
                    color: #359115;
                    font-weight:bold;
                    }

                    #wrapper {
                        position: absolute;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                        text-align: center;
                    }

                    #container {
                        background-color: #dddddd;
                        /*height: 100%;
                        widows: 100%;*/
                        margin: 0,auto;
                        text-align: center;
                    }



        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="container" align="center">
                <span class="currency">$ </span><span class="integer">4,080,048.</span><span class="decimal">00</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### EDIT:

I need that to work for a webView in Android and IOS, from some reason the numbers are always appear at the top of the browser.
**NOTE: The browser are not full screen!**

The screenshot is in my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908214/android-ios-webview-get-height-with-javascript)

Comment: There's a syntax error in your CSS: `margin: 0,auto;` should be `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: It's still not working

Comment: In your sample code the `#container` is full width, which technically is "centred". What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you want the `#container` to fill up the screen and have the content centered vertically and horizontally?

Comment: To put container in the middle of the page

Comment: I assume he wants to center the content vertically because he mentioned unknown height

Comment: In that case, it's already centred vertically as well since the `body`'s height is `auto`.

Comment: So how to put all the content in the middle of the page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center a DIV horizontally and vertically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123999/center-a-div-horizontally-and-vertically)

Comment: It's not a duplication, because all the example has fixed sizes

Comment: if you don't care about `IE8` support take a look at my answer

Comment: I thought it's a simple HTML problem, but seems that mobile devices needs more corrections, please see the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to put div in center of page with unknown size of div height?

A simple solution involving 2d transforms (with negative translate values for X and Y axis):

http://jsbin.com/itifad/1/edit

CSS

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);    /* Older Gecko browser */
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);     /* IE9+ */
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

and this is all: no need to use javascript or nested elements, to define the height of parent containers or use tricky display properties.

Further reference: http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/transforms2d (not working on `IE<=8`)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <style>
            body{
                margin: 0; /* There is no margin, padding or border on html, only margin: 8px; on body... */
                background-color: #FFFFFF; /* Why transparent? Changed to white... */ 
                font-family: "Helvetica";
                color: #359115;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            #wrapper {
                position: relative;
                width: 50%;
                margin: auto;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #container {
                background-color: #dddddd;
                margin: 0 auto;
                text-align: center;
            }



        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="container" align="center">
                <span class="currency">$ </span><span class="integer">4,080,048.</span><span class="decimal">00</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And if you want it to be in the absolute center, x and y, you need to change this in the style:

```
        #wrapper {
            position: relative;
            width: 50%;
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #container {
            background-color: #dddddd;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

To this:

```
        #wrapper {
            position: relative;
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #container {
            background-color: #dddddd;
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way.  For the **HTML**, add a `.wrapper` container around your content:

```
<div id="container"> 
    <div class="wrapper">
    <span class="currency">₪</span><span class="integer">4,080.</span><span class="decimal">00</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Assuming you want to center this is a page (viewport), I would use the following **CSS**:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family:"Helvetica";
    color: #359115;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#container {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#container .wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**How This Works**

Set the display type to `table` for the `#container` and use absolute positioning to make it stretch to the edges of the viewport.

Set the `.wrapper` to display type `table-cell`, set the height to 100%, and then use `vertical-align: middle` to get vertical
centering, and `text-align: center` for horizontal centering.

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/mBDcg/

Answer (score 1):

`display:table` is the easiest way to accomplish this. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/bRgrf/4/

```
html,body{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
            }
            body{
                background-color: transparent; 
                overflow: hidden;
                font-family: "Helvetica";
                    color: #359115;
                    font-weight:bold;
    display:table;
                    }


                    #container {
                        background-color: #dddddd;
                        height: 100%;
                        width: 100%;
                        margin: 0;
                        text-align: center;
                        vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
                    }
```