# Centering div element inside another div element

Tags: css, html, primefaces

I have the following HTML code generated by [Primefaces's components](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf) (I've only considered HTML important code)

```
<html>
    <body>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/tiendaVirtual/css/init.css" /></head><body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header">
            //Header content
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="dvLogin">
                <div id="pnlLogin" class="ui-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all pnlLogin" data-widget="widget_pnlLogin">
                    <div id="pnlLogin_header" class="ui-panel-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
                        <span class="ui-panel-title">Login</span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="pnlLogin_content" class="ui-panel-content ui-widget-content">
                    </div>
                <div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            //Footer content
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And your css file init.css:

```
body{
    font-size: 12px !important;
}

#page{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute !important;
}

#header{
    height: auto !important;
    top: 0;
}

#content{
    height: 100% !important;
    display: block;

}

#footer{
    height: auto !important;
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%; 
    bottom: 0;
}
.dvLogin{
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 660px !important;
}

.pnlLogin{
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto auto !important;
}

#pnlFooter{
    margin-bottom: 10px !important
```

This generate the following HTML page:

[image]

I want that panel called 'Login' is centered vertically and horizontally but I don't know as...

PD:

I added the XHTML pages:

login.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="/templates/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form prependId="false">
        <div id="dvLogin">

            <p:panel id="pnlLogin" header="Login" styleClass="pnlLogin">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Usuario"/>
                    <p:inputText id="txtUsuario" value="#{loginBean.usuario}" required="true" requiredMessage="Especificar usuario"/> 
                    <p:outputLabel value="Contraseña"/>
                    <p:password id="pswContrasenia" value="#{loginBean.contrasenia}" required="true" requiredMessage="Especificar contraseña"/>  
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton value="Ingresar" action="#{loginBean.ingresar}" />
            </p:panel>
        </div>
        </h:form>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

template.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:loadBundle basename="resources.application" var="msg"/>

<h:head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/css/init.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header">
            <ui:insert name="header" >
              <ui:include src="/templates/header.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <ui:insert name="content">

            </ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <ui:insert name="footer" >
              <ui:include src="/templates/footer.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
    </div>


</h:body>
</html>
```

header.xhtml

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <p:panel>
        <p:graphicImage value="/img/common/logo.png" />
    </p:panel>
</ui:composition>
```

footer.xhtml

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <p:panel id="pnlFooter">
        Everis Peru &#169; - Shoppping Cart
    </p:panel>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: What about the css inside `init.css` ? can you replicate this using a http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center a DIV horizontally and vertically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123999/center-a-div-horizontally-and-vertically)

Comment: init.css is css file that I've posted

Comment: The css you've shared isn't replicating the image you've posted..

Comment: For this, You need the original XHTML pages. I added

Comment: The answer (accepted by you) shows it is not really PrimeFaces related, so adding it to the title is not only superfluous (it is already tagged that way) but sort of wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things that you need to look.

1) there is no need of unwanted position absolute and !important tags this can be simple achieved with diaplay: table properties as follows

**CSS**

```
#content:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */

  /* For visualization 
  background: #808080; width: 5px;
  */
 }

#dvLogin {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: #a0a0a0 solid 1px;
  background: #f00;
 }

html, body{height:100%;}
```

[Demo - jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3zj9/1/)  i.e. in full screen [Demo full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/d3zj9/1/show/)

also you need to check CSS as unwanted css are commented in above demo. so Please check that

**[Reference Link](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)**

Hope it Helps!