# Basic responsive page with centered content

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a webpage and I'm using Jquery mobile.

I have an image and un text and I would like to center the content in my page horizontaly and verticaly, and when I modify the width of the window, the content should adapt.

Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/NrCGb/570/) :

In the example, the content adapt correctly, but it's not centered. if I set the style of my content div to :

```
style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto;width: 500px;"
```

To my div, the content is centered but no longer adapt...

Can you update my jsfiddle to do what I need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with `display: table;` on the outer and `display:table-cell` on the inner container to center stuff vertically. Check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/NrCGb/578/

**EDIT** Max width 500px for content:

**http://jsfiddle.net/NrCGb/585/**

Comment: Thanks, it works but I would like to have my content with a 500px width in the center

Comment: updated my answer. It would be good though if you would also try yourself a bit because this is actually very basic stuff.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the basic question, I'm really a beginner and was struggling for a long time...

Comment: Don't be sorry for asking a basic question. :) It would be just good if you try yourself and then ask again if you are stuck. Anyway, glad I was able to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

(example: 502 Bad Gateway)
jQuery Mobile is not good for customization. Use it as it is or don't use it at all. After two projects with it, I find no benefit, just headache. 
Try with !important

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
#content {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -250px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 500px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wesleysmits/NrCGb/581/

This article could prove useful to you as well
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

This stackoverflow thread might also help you.
[Center a DIV horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123999/center-a-div-horizontally-and-vertically)