# How to center horizontally and vertically a select box

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center horizontally and vertically a select box

Here is jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/j3r9Lp81/

CSS:

```
div.currency {
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="currency">
            <select id="currencies">
                <option value="GBP">Great Britain Pound</option>
                <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
                <option value="USD">US Dollar</option>
                <option value="AUD">Australian Dollar</option>
                <option value="CAD">Canadian Dollar</option>
                <option value="JPY">Japanese Yen</option>
                <option value="CHF">Swiss Franc</option>
                <option value="SEK">Swedish Krona</option>
                <option value="NZD">New Zealand Dollar</option>
                <option value="NZD">Hong Kong Dollar</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Center it relative to what?

Comment: There are several methods: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Comment: This question has been asked many times. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123999/center-a-div-horizontally-and-vertically

Comment: @kmoe: Relative to `#wrapper` I think ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this to center horizontally and vertically the select box.

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j3r9Lp81/2/)

**CSS:**

```
div.wrapper {
    background: #F00;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    display: table;
}
div.currency {
    text-align:center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't get how I can style it horizontally without adding a `height` for `div.wrapper`

Comment: @Tibbers If you remove the height then it will look like this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/j3r9Lp81/3/ but it'll be center vertically if there is some height to your `div.wrapper` and please let me know if you want to know or do something else. :)

Comment: @Tibbers "Unfortunately I didn't get how I can style it horizontally without adding a height for div.wrapper" - What do you mean? I really don't understand how you want to style it horizontally without adding a height and could you please show me an image or screenshot or working demo that show me what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Let's take an example that I want have single page website with only 1 select box and I have a full width image as a background. My idea was without specifying height and weight center the select box.

Comment: @Tibbers JSFiddle demo - http://jsfiddle.net/j3r9Lp81/7/ and http://jsfiddle.net/j3r9Lp81/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it setting an height for the wrapper element and setting it to `position: relative` then you can use `position: absolute` for centering the child element.

**CSS**

```
div.wrapper{
    position:relative;
    background:red;
    height:100px;
}
div.currency {
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
}
```

Comment: I like this method but you have to say that won't work in old browsers

Comment: it should work in IE9+, FF3.5+ chrome4+, Opera10.5+, Safari3.1+ :: According to > http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d