# Div Image not centered vertically and horizontally?

Tags: html, image, centering

My image is not centering with the heading at the top no matter what I try.
If anyone can provide me with a code correction it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 675px;
  height: 418px;
  margin-top: -250px;
  /* Half the height */
  margin-left: -250px;
  /* Half the width */
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Text</h1>
<div class="img">
  <img src="rsz_damon600.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center a DIV horizontally and vertically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123999/center-a-div-horizontally-and-vertically)

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem. I was supposed to change the margin top and left to half the size of width and height. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Reference</title>
<style>
img {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    color : white;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Text</h1>
<div class="img">
  <img src="rsz_damon600.png">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should set margin-top and margin-left as half the size of width and height.

or if you don't know the size of element,you can use

**transform: translate(-50%, -50%);**

to center it both vertically and horizontally

```
img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   /* width: 675px;
   height: 418px; */
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

another method：

```
img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   margin: auto;
}
```

this is a [guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

Use css trick `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`:

```css
img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   width: 675px;
   height: 418px;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


body {
    background-color: black;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    color : white;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<style>
</style>
<body>

<h1>Text</h1>
<div class="img">
  <img src="http://www.motorverso.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/iNFINITI-q60-1_1280x792-675x418.jpg">
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do it like this. Place the image inside a div element. Then set margin for div as auto. :)

```
<div name="my_div"style="margin:auto;">
      <img src="" id="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing `left:50%` to `left:43%`. That should get you where you want to be.