# centre a div containing other divs which is dependent to each other

Tags: html, css

I am using a pure CSS Loader as a loading stuff in my project. Called whenever its loading the new page or opening for the first time.

HTML code for the loader

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="lds-ripple">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code for the loader

```
.lds-ripple {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
  }
  .lds-ripple div {
    position: absolute;
    border: 4px solid rgb(0, 225, 255);
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: lds-ripple 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0.2, 0.8, 1) infinite;
  }
  .lds-ripple div:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: -0.5s;
  }
  @keyframes lds-ripple {
    0% {
      top: 28px;
      left: 28px;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      top: -1px;
      left: -1px;
      width: 58px;
      height: 58px;
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

I want to place it horizontally and vertically center of the body but don't want to apply any CSS to the body because it will affect the other elements of my project. Now I have gone through some of the examples in stack overflow like

[How to center an element horizontally and vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

And

[Center a DIV horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123999/center-a-div-horizontally-and-vertically)

And 2-3 more examples but they didn't worked for me. Maybe because of the position type of the CSS class `.lds-ripple` its giving problem. Is there any way to place this loader horizontally or vertically center of the body without applying any css to the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change `css` of `lds-ripple`

```css
.lds-ripple {
    position: absolute;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
  .lds-ripple div {
    position: absolute;
    border: 4px solid rgb(0, 225, 255);
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: lds-ripple 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0.2, 0.8, 1) infinite;
  }
  .lds-ripple div:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: -0.5s;
  }
  @keyframes lds-ripple {
    0% {
      top: 28px;
      left: 28px;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      top: -1px;
      left: -1px;
      width: 58px;
      height: 58px;
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="lds-ripple">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added

```
.lds-ripple {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   width: 64px;
   height: 64px;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```css
 
body, html {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
}
.lds-ripple {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 64px;
height: 64px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  .lds-ripple div {
position: absolute;
border: 4px solid rgb(0, 225, 255);
opacity: 1;
border-radius: 50%;
animation: lds-ripple 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0.2, 0.8, 1) infinite;
  }
  .lds-ripple div:nth-child(2) {
animation-delay: -0.5s;
  }
  @keyframes lds-ripple {
0% {
  top: 28px;
  left: 28px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
100% {
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  opacity: 0;
}
  }
```

```html
 <div class="lds-ripple">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```